# How to add active class with JQuery on a custom element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a custom card component with plain html and css. This is my code for HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-title">
            Title 1
        </div>
        <div class="item-subtitle">
            <label>test, test, test</label>
            <i class="icon-basket remove-item"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my css code for the styling:

```
.item {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;    
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(176, 176, 176, 0.2);
}


    .item:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #EEF5FF;
    }

.item-title {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 24px;
}

.item-subtitle {
    padding-left: 24px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

    .item-subtitle label {
        width: calc(100% - 64px);
        display: inline-block;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
```

The card component is looking good. Now I want to add an active class to the item. I have made a hover and when I click on the item and I want that the hover color stays (active).

This is my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('item').click(function(){
    $('item').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

The hover is working good but when I click on it the background-color doesn't stay active.

I have made a jsfiddle so you can see the behaviour:

https://jsfiddle.net/gvu9nk8d/2/

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: your selector should be $('.item') and you forget to add active class :    
                                                                                                                
    .active { 
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #EEF5FF;
    }

Comment: Works fine with the typo fixed and a definition of active.  https://jsfiddle.net/ra7p1980/

Comment: Possible confusion as you don't have a "custom element" - you have a `div` with a class.  So you need to use class selector not element selector (ie "[dot]class" `.class`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you need to correct
1. your jquery click event selector is missing dot for class `item`
2. You need to add class `active` in the CSS

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.item').click(function(){ //added dot here
    $('.item').removeClass("active");//added dot here
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

```css
.item {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;    
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(176, 176, 176, 0.2);
}


    .item:hover, .item.active { /* added class here*/
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #EEF5FF;
    }

.item-title {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 24px;
}

.item-subtitle {
    padding-left: 24px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

    .item-subtitle label {
        width: calc(100% - 64px);
        display: inline-block;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-title">
   Title 1
        </div>
        <div class="item-subtitle">
            <label>test, test, test</label>
            <i class="icon-basket remove-item"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pvaef6hx/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the dot at class item

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.item').click(function(){
         $('.item').removeClass("active");
         $(this).addClass("active");
       });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code was that you have used the wrong selector.
It should be `$('.item')` since item is a class. Then the active class will be added

Also include some style to make changes when the item is active